# Ajax POST no success nor error not DUPLICATE

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im experiencing a weird error in an ajax request. upon calling an alert in both error and succes, the alerts arent displayed. This implies that the ajax request isn't processed. But I have no clue whatsoever why this is the case. Code is below.

```
var bool;

function set(n, thread_id) {
    bool = n;
//  update_upvotes(thread_id);
}


function vote(thread_id) {
    if (bool == 1) {
        alert("begin ajax");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../includes/thread_upvotes.inc.php",
            data: {
                thread_id: thread_id
            },
            succes: function(data) {
                alert("data:"+data);
            },
            error: function() { 
                alert("hi, im broken");
            }     
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../includes/thread_downvotes.inc.php",
            data: {
                thread_id: thread_id
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here the form which calls the function

```
<iframe class="foo" name="foo" id="foo"></iframe>

<form class="voteform" target="foo" onsubmit="vote('.$thread_id.') & update_upvotes('.$thread_id.');">
    <button onclick="set(1);" id="'.$thread_id.'1" name="upvote" type= "submit" class="vote right up" value="'.$thread_id.'"> '.$num_upvotes.' </button>
    <button onclick="set(0);" id="'.$thread_id.'0" name="downvote" type= "submit" class="vote left down" value="'.$thread_id.'"> '.$num_downvotes.' </button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This post has been marked as a duplicate, the answer provided by the person who marked this as a duplicate is not satisfactory. We removed the form out of our code and the ajax request is still not being processed...

Comment: why do you have a global number called `bool`?

Comment: for data trafficking,a bit messy but the error isn't in that part.

Comment: I know, but if you write code like that, how can you have any confidence that it is working?

Comment: It's a make shift fix to something else for the time being.

Comment: Just to be clear, begin ajax is occuring, right?

Comment: yes, it is occurring

Comment: Your form is submitting and refreshing the page.

Comment: no we tried removing the form entirely, still nothing happens. Neither a success message, nor an error message :/

Comment: One problem is that "succes" should be spelled "success". Kevin B is also correct that there's nothing stopping the form from submitting after you start the request.

Comment: hmm thanks for replying to this duped thread! the ajax request was indeed successful, and that is the reason why the alert wasn't engaged. I figured out the bug now, it was far deeper than we thought and was found in the structure of the table in the database

Answer (score 0):

It seems this `url` `"../includes/thread_upvotes.inc.php",` is wrong. Remove the `dots`

Comment: removing the dots on the link unfortunately doesn't fix the problem

Comment: can you please look at the network tab and console & let know if any call is made?Also console window may show some error

Comment: The console window is completely empty, the network tab however, shows 4 requests being made.